# Pass-through pipe with timeout

Tags: pipe, timeout

How can I implement a timeout when no data is being passed through a pipe? It would act as watchdog with following usage:

`process1 | watchdog --timeout 60 | process2`

When no data pipes through I would like the watchdog process to close.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To begin with the watchdog pipeline from your question would probably not kill the `process1` unless it is trying again to write to the dead pipe. So your watchdog should somehow explicitly kill process1.

Beside this here a very simple `watchdog.sh` shell script. You can test it interactively in console. Just type `./watchdog.sh`. It will duplicate everything you type then and stop if you don't type something for 5 seconds.

```
#!/bin/bash

# first arg is timeout (default: 5)
T="${1:-5}"
PID=$$

exec tee >(bash -c '
while true ; do
    bytes=$(timeout '$T' cat | wc -c)
    if ! [ "$bytes" -gt 0 ] ;then
            break
    fi
done
## add something like "killall process1", for now we just kill this tee command
kill -9 '$PID)
```

Note the script will actually timeout between T and 2*T (otherwise it would be way more complicated). Somehow you could add a way to kill `process1` as I initially mentioned.

Below an example for testing.

process1.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "here we are ..."
sleep 2
echo "still alive ..."
sleep 20
echo "too late ..."
```

And run it like this (inclusive an ugly method to kill process1.sh on timeout):

```
(./process1.sh & echo $! >/tmp/pid; wait) |(./watchdog.sh 5; kill `cat /tmp/pid`)
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks very promising. I do have binary data, would that work alright? If I understand correctly, it's based on `cat`.

Comment: `tee` is copying the data through the pipe without changing it.  I've added an example for testing.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be ideal in terms of performance, and it's line based, but the timeout feature of the `read` command might be used for this. In `bash`, you can then use a command line stanza like the following as your `watchdog --timeout 60` part:

```
while read -r -s -t 60 line ; do printf "%s\n" "$line" ; done
```

`zsh` offers a similar `read` command.

Note however, that it won't actually terminate the overall command until the first part, i.e., your `process1`, decides to terminate due to its standard output being closed.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative view of the problem might be to remove the watchdog out of the pipe, and stat the pipe for its last modification time.  For example,

```
(
process1 &
pid=$!
old=0
while   new=$(stat -L /dev/stderr -c %Y)
        [ $new != $old ]
do      old=$new
        sleep 60
done 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3   &&   kill -hup $pid
) |
process2
```

This puts process1 into the background so we can get its pid, then polls the last modification time of the output pipe.  If it doesn't change in 60 seconds, we can kill the pid.  To be able to capture the output of `stat` we swap file descriptor 1, which is the pipe, with stderr and stat that instead.